# C# Unit test does not step-into code

Tags: c#, debugging, nunit

I am trying to write unit test for a C# implementation in Visual Studio 2013 with .Net 4.5. This solution was created in VS2010 but now it is imported to VS 2013.

I have original code in assembly X and the unit tests in assembly Y.
When I run unit tests from assembly Y then it does not execute the methods in assembly X and in the debug logs I can see following message.
--*Stepping over non-user code*

Any idea what I will be missing in the settings etc. ?

Comment: Did you link to assembly Y to _project_ X? probably you linked to _compiled assembly_

Comment: It is linked to the project X, not the compiled assembly and I tried to reset this reference many times.

Comment: Have you checked the `supportedRuntime` section in your nunit.exe.config file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The method under test was returning IEnumerable, so that will never be called due to lazy loading.